Lenovo ThinkSystem LOM is not connected
I'm building Lenovo ThinkSystem server(SR650) with Intel X722 LOM. Actually the server is came up with fully assembled so i haven't done any physical setup except cabling.
I could install OS successfully and then tried to configure network but figured out that the ethernet adapter is not working. I've checked that on bios mode there was some network menu and it said all ethernet ports is not connected. It seems the server knows what LOM adapter is connected since the name is on the list on bios mode.
Also i can't not see the LED for ethernet. I don't think the cable is problem because it worked when plugging in Xclarity port. If any additional info is required please let me know.

Which LOM is there? Have you tried to loopback ports of LOM to each other to see if it's physically working (you need to put them "up" in some OS for that)? If it isn't, ask your vendor about faulty hardware. What kind of a device is on the other end of a cable an what kind of a cable (e.g. MDI or MDI-X) you are using? Maybe, there is a hard speed mismatch (e.g. LOM wants strictly 10GE, no more no less, and the other side can't do this)?

It's Intel X722 LOM and yes the support team said it should be gigabit internet but my office uses 100Mbit internet. I should ask my boss to upgrade our internet plan or so. Thank you for your help!

X722 NIC is 10 gigabit ethernet only. It can't connect with 100 mbit or 1 gigabit ethernet cards: > NOTE: only 10GbE single-rate optics are supported. Do not use dual-rate 1GbE/10GbE optics with this adapter. So 1 gigabit won't suffice too. You must use 10 gigabit ethernet equipment on the other side too to connect.

The figure 5 is what i have on my machine https://lenovopress.lenovo.com/lp0654-intel-x722-integrated-controller. And it seems it's ok to use 1gb?

Intel Ethernet Connection X722 is a network controller embedded into the Intel C624 "Lewisburg" PCH chipset of Lenovo ThinkSystem servers. The controller connects to available 10 GbE and 1 Gigabit Ethernet LAN-on-motherboard (LOM) adapter cards. Obviously, my comment doesn't apply to this. I thought your server has a dedicated X722 card, and not a built into PCH one. You should have provided this link from the very beginning!

Sorry for that  I didn't know there is so much variation of X722.

@NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for the flags. I put the discussion in comments, feel free to erase it if you think it's better to remove, but I thought the discussion was helpful to isolate the problem. I edited your comment to state "my comment" and not "my answer".
